# Create a matrix from a vector where each row is a shifted version of the vector

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array like this

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and I want to create an array that looks like this:

```
array([[4, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Thereby, each row corresponds to `ar` which is shifted by the row index + 1.

A straightforward implementation could look like this:

```
ar_roll = np.tile(ar, ar.shape[0]).reshape(ar.shape[0], ar.shape[0])

for indi, ri in enumerate(ar_roll):
    ar_roll[indi, :] = np.roll(ri, indi + 1)
```

which gives me the desired output.

My question is whether there is a smarter way of doing this which avoids the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) basically padding with the leftover elements and then the `strides` helping us in creating that shifted version pretty efficiently -

```
def strided_method(ar):
    a = np.concatenate(( ar, ar[:-1] ))
    L = len(ar)
    n = a.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a[L-1:], (L,L), (-n,n))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [42]: ar = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [43]: strided_method(ar)
Out[43]: 
array([[4, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [44]: ar = np.array([4,9,3,6,1,2])

In [45]: strided_method(ar)
Out[45]: 
array([[2, 4, 9, 3, 6, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 9, 3, 6],
       [6, 1, 2, 4, 9, 3],
       [3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 9],
       [9, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4],
       [4, 9, 3, 6, 1, 2]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [5]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

# @Eric's soln
In [6]: %timeit roll_matrix(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.39 ms per loop

# @Warren Weckesser's soln
In [8]: %timeit circulant(a[::-1])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop

# Strides method
In [18]: %timeit strided_method(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.7 µs per loop
```

Making a copy (if you want to make changes and not just use as a read only array) won't hurt us too badly for the `strides` method -

```
In [19]: %timeit strided_method(a).copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 381 µs per loop
```

Comment: This uses less memory than my solution, but the output is not safely writeable. I doubt that's an issue though, making this the better solution

Comment: @Eric: What do you mean by "not safely writeable"?

Comment: @Cleb: I mean that if you try and change one of the `4`s in the array, all of them will change at once!

Comment: @Eric: Ok, creating a copy should then avoid this issue, I assume?

Comment: @Cleb Yup, should be fine then.

Comment: Thanks for the timings!

Comment: Turns out that the online numpy docs don't actually include documentation for `as_strided` - I've submitted [a patch to enable building that page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9039)

Comment: @Eric Yup, the documentation part needs some work for sure. We have been using those Scipy docs for it thus far. Thanks for the submit!

Comment: @Divakar: can you add `scipy.linalg.circulant` to your benchmark?

Comment: @Eric Sure! Added.

Comment: I suspect `as_strided` is left somewhat hidden because it is a "dangerous" function.  A mistake in the arguments can lead to the python interpreter crashing (segfaults, memory access violations, and all that).

Comment: Hi Divakar, care to revisit [your PR in SciPy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7833)?

Comment: @percusse Ah yes! Had that in mind. Keep losing it though. Would get back soon, hopefully in few days. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @Divakar: Glad to see it got incorporated now, thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 5):

Both of the existing answers are fine; this answer is probably only of interest if you are already using scipy.

The matrix that you describe is known as a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).  If you don't mind the dependency on scipy, you can use [`scipy.linalg.circulant`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html) to create one:

```
In [136]: from scipy.linalg import circulant

In [137]: ar = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [138]: circulant(ar[::-1])
Out[138]: 
array([[4, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: I do use scipy, so that answer is very helpful, as it is also the most readable one (upvoted). In terms of speed it seems less efficient though, but great that there is already a built-in for it!

Comment: Looks like scipy is worth of a patch to use @Divakar's faster implementation. You can see the scipy implementation [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/linalg/special_matrices.py#L206-L243)

Comment: @Eric Good idea! Scipy could use some strides tricks for sure!

Comment: A function with better performance would be great.  I'm not so sure about returning an array with funky strides.  That would be a backwards incompatible change--we have no idea how folks use the result of `circulant`.  Anyway, further discussion should be over in a scipy issue on github, or in the scipy-dev mailing list.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Returning `funky_strides.copy()` is still a 10x speedup on this small data, and would be invisible to the user

Comment: *"...would be invisible to the user"*  Yes, right up until they start modifying the array in-place.  Then, at least for the unsuspecting user, the fun begins.

Comment: Trying to force the issue again as I would love to see SciPy use some `strides` benefit. Could you explain on the "fun begins" part? As @Eric pointed out with a copy, it should be okay as the output would have its own memory space separate from the input array. Hope I am not missing something here.

Comment: and I meant if we make the copy inside the function `circulant`. I am guessing should be okay then.

Comment: Hmmm...  if a copy with "regular" strides is returned, I don't recall what I was worried about.  And if there is still a big performance gain, it sounds like a worthwhile change.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Awesome! So, how should I proceed on it? Should I log an issue on `github.com/scipy/scipy/issues` with tags : `enhancement`, etc. linking to this SO post? Looks like you are a contributor on SciPy, so would be nice to get some guidance.

Comment: @Divakar: Creating a new issue with a description of the improvement would be a great start. Creating a pull request that *implements* the improvement would be even better!  See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/HACKING.rst.txt for information about contributing to scipy.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach

```
def roll_matrix(vec):
    N = len(vec)
    buffer = np.empty((N, N*2 - 1))

    # generate a wider array that we want a slice into
    buffer[:,:N] = vec
    buffer[:,N:] = vec[:-1]

    rolled = buffer.reshape(-1)[N-1:-1].reshape(N, -1)
    return rolled[:,:N]
```

In your case, we build `buffer` to be

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

Then flatten it, trim it, reshape it to get `rolled`:

```
array([[ 4.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  1.,  2.]])
```

And finally, slice off the garbage last columns