# Construct n x n matrix with unique value from 1 to n in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I have two lists in Python

`P = [P1, P2 ..... Pn]`, `D = [D1, D2 ..... Dn]`.

I want to create a matrix in such a way that each cell should contain a value from `1` to `n`. Cell value should be unique both in the row and column and each time it should generate different combination.

Sample output is shown below for `n=3` and arbitrary `P` and `D` both of size 3.

Anyone has any idea of generating such matrix?

[image: n x n matrix]

Comment: You could start with circulant matrix and iterate over all permutation of rows and columns. I'm not sure if all such matrices can be enumerated this way

Comment: Related: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43735034/1534017)

Comment: What you are looking for is sudoku generating algorithm. Hope this helps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-sudoku-generator/amp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import random

def createMatrix(n):
    firstRow = random.sample(range(n),n)
    permutes = random.sample(range(n),n)
    return list(firstRow[i:]+firstRow[:i] for i in permutes)


N = 5
m = createMatrix(N)
print(m)
```

Which for the case of `N=5` gives (after converting to `numpy` array for the printing):

```
[[4 0 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 4 0]
 [3 4 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 0 1]]
```

In the case of values starting from 1 the correction to the function is:

```
def createMatrix(n):
    firstRow = random.sample(range(1, n + 1),n)
    permutes = random.sample(range(1, n + 1),n)
    return list(firstRow[i:]+firstRow[:i] for i in permutes)
```

Comment: I guess the OP doesn't want `0` is his/her matrix. Other than that great answer! +1

Comment: This look like a sudoku board but it's very easy to solve (because we just shift the position of each row)

Answer (score -1):

Solution without modules and by pattern.
You can input anything you want in P1, and will give you a matrix

```
P1 = list(range(1, 101))

matrix_len = len(P1)
w, h = matrix_len, matrix_len
matrix = [[None for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
counter=0
for i in range(matrix_len):
    for j in range(matrix_len):
        matrix[counter][j] = i
        counter +=1
        if counter == matrix_len:
            counter= 0
    counter +=1

print(matrix)
```

Comment: thanks, but this solution generate just one output. I needed a solution which generate different combination on each run, which was provided by David's solution above.